# Save Information User Inputs to Program

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am writing an inventory based C# Windows Form Application as a "for-fun" project during my free time in school.

I want to save all the users info so that when they exit the app and reload it again, all of their information is still there. I could do extremely basic and go with a text file but I would like to learn something from this project other than something I already know how to do already.

What would be the next-level up from a text file (if that is the right terms) ? Would it be best to use a small local database for the information.

I am currently using a Linear Linked List for the data structure of choice and I have a merge sort written for it already for when adding products.

Would it make sense to stick to a text file or just go to small local database within the app?

Thank you.

Comment: As you mentioned you already know about text file then go for the local database and get hands-on something new .

Comment: The next step is Local DB or Sql things (MySql , MSSql, PostgreSql etc.)

Comment: @Yee: why did you delete your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542248/large-number-multiplication-with-arrays/55543119 ?